# Threads inside JUnit Test Case to test SharedResource class

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, runnable

The code snippet below is in my JUnit Test Case class. I am using three threads to test a class called SharedResources; getGuy is just one of them. My problem is after starting the threads, only the first one reads the sharedResource, and that only once.

```
Thread getGuy = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("I consume",resource.get());
            }//for
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: need more context, more code.

Comment: +1 more context. what are you expecting it to do? what's the test scenario your trying to run (ie, what do the other two threads do and what do you expect to be the outcome)? what do the other threads do with the resource? any sleeps in your code will make for unpredictable tests... well, at least unpredictable interleaving make the test hard to write

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic producer-consumer design. Instead of creating producer and consumer classes, I simply create the sharedResource class. Then in the JUnit Test Case, I create the producer and consumer Threads. getGuy is a consumer thread.

Thanks